# Linux boot hangs

Tags: kernel, boot, linux-kernel

I have been having a problem recently with one of my computers getting Linux to boot. I mainly use Manjaro or Linux Mint and so far both have been running into the same problem at boot. The following kernel output shows and the the boot just hangs at the end of the message.

```
starting version 231
AMD-vi: Event Logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=2:00.0 domain 0x0011 address=0x00000000009d600 flags = 0x0000]
nouveau 0000:01:00.0 gr: failed to load fecs_inst
nouveau 0000:01:00.0 DRM: Pointer to flat panel table invalid
ata7: Comreset failed (errno=-16)
ata7: Comreset failed (errno=-16)
ata7: Comreset failed (errno=-16)
ata7: Comreset failed (errno=-16)
ata7: reset failed, giving up
```

I tried enabling `iommu` for `amd-vi` in my BIOS just to see if that made a difference, but it did nothing.
If I understand this output right its trying to connect to a device (in my pcie slot 2:00.0) and the device in this slot is a RAID card that does not work with Linux. However I only use the card with my Windows partition and do not need Linux to connect to it anyway.

Is there a way I can tell the kernel just to ignore this device if it is indeed causing problems?